# Do I use .append here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using this function I wrote:

```
def Dish_get_info() -> Dish:
""" Prompt user for fields of dish; create and return.
"""
print()
return Dish(
    input("Please enter the Dish's name:  "),
    float(input("Please enter the Dish's price:  ")),
    int(input("Please enter the Dish's calories:  ")))
```

I need to create function that asks the user if they want to add a dish.
If 'yes', the function runs Dish_get_info() and adds the dish (namedtuple already define) into a list.
If 'no', the function prints out all Dishes already in the list.

I've wrote this so far.

```
def Menu_enter():
while True:
    Menu = [ ]
    n = input('Do you want to add a dish?  ')
    if n == 'yes':

        d = Dish_get_info()
        Menu.append(Dish_str(d))

    if n =='no':
        print (Menu.append(Dish_str(d)))
        break
```

but I'm not sure the .append() method works for this case

Comment: Look what the docs say about `append`: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html .

Comment: I know what it does but it's not returning the altered list outside of the function

Comment: `list.append` returns `None` and change the list.

Comment: as an aside -- the way you're compartmentalizing your functions is great! Consider moving them to another module so you can further isolate your code. [See my implementation here](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/77af58a43bdcaf9c57ac)

Answer (score 1):

Append works, it is your loop that is giving you trouble. You are reinitializing your list every single time you loop. The menu should be outside the while loop.

```
def Menu_enter():
    Menu = []

    while True:
        n = input('Do you want to add a dish?  ')
        if n == 'yes':
            d = Dish_get_info()
            Menu.append(Dish_str(d))
        if n == 'no':
            break 

    print(Menu)
```